# How to draw net\Grid on image with scale bar? [ WPF,C#]

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[[image]

The numbers\letters on the scale bar should be customise, for example:can start at 230 - 450 with 30 between each number.
The numbers should stand by the end of the net. the net customise to the image.
How can I do it on xaml without code behind (Dependency property)?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I added an image.

Answer (score -1):

You are better served if you use a plotting library, and display the image inside a plotting area with gridlines displayed.

A nice plotting library for WPF that most probably would do what you want is [Oxyplot](http://www.oxyplot.org/).